# Start Date Picker date from a String Date

Tags: android, datepicker

Hi I have a question is there anyway that I could start the date of a datepicker from a textView which contains a date?

Here is my code:

```
public void openDatePicker()
{
    // Get Current Date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(rentActivity.this,
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
            {
                endDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
            }
        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()-1000);
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

and the string containing the date is txtDate

Thank you for the help in advance! :D

Comment: you can take one textview and on click of that show date picker

Comment: @curiousMind Actually sir what I am wondering is that. For say, I have a text containing the date 25/1/2016, and when I open the datepicker it will start from the date in the textview sir :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make the following changes to your function, I have mentioned comments wherever changes have been done

```
public void openDatePicker() {
        // Get Current Date
        final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                        endDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);

                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

        // get the date from TextView
        String startDate = txtDate.getText().toString();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            date = simpleDateFormat.parse(startDate); // parse the String according to the desired format
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // set the date as minDate
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(date.getTime());
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Insert this after you instantiate your calendar object.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dd/MM/yyyy);
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(textView.getText().toString());
c.setTime(date);
```

Be careful to [format the SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you sir, for you answer I appreciate it. Actually I thought of using datepickerdialog.updateDate(); function but I guess there was another way haha :D